# Baposter Boxheader Vertical Alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, baposter

Texts of boxheaders are aligned differently if there are ascenders/descenders. Examples are shown below. The alignment of the title for box on the right seems weird to me. How can I adjust this?

[image]

Baposter is a document class for creating posters. It is not available on CTAN, but can be downloaded from http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default header boxes have `0pt` depth. This is the default for any node (see section 5.1 of the `TikZ` manual). To align letters on the baseline, you need to add `text depth = 0.25ex` to the macro that creates the headerbox. It is the same issue as here: [How to “fix baselines” in tikz nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47106/)

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper]{baposter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}[1]{
  \path (\baposter@box@name nw) + (0em,-0.5\baposter@box@@boxheaderheight)
        node[anchor=west,inner sep=0.4em,text depth=0.25ex] {#1};% <-- added text depth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
  grid=false,
  columns=2,
  colspacing=4.2mm,
  headerheight=0.10\textheight,
  background=none,
  eyecatcher=false,
  %posterbox options
  headerborder=closed,
  borderColor=red,
  headershape=rectangle,
  headershade=plain,
  headerColorOne=blue,
  textborder=rectangle,
  boxshade=plain,
  boxColorOne=white,
  headerFontColor=white,
  headerfont=\color{white}\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  textfont=\normalsize\sffamily,
  linewidth=1pt
}
{}
{Title}
{\textsc{Author}}
{}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box1,column=0,row=0,span=1]{M}
Hello
\end{posterbox}

\begin{posterbox}[name=box2,column=1,row=0,span=1]{Mp}
Hello
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer only provides for posterboxes that are rectangular i.e. `baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle`, not the option with rounded corners. If using a different posterbox style, the appropriate box drawing macro will need to be altered.